# Passing the control as CommandParameter programmatically

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, command, commandparameter

When trying to pass the control in `xaml`, we write the following code:

```
<MenuItem x:Name="NewMenuItem" Command="{Binding MenuItemCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}" />
```

I'm trying to create a `MenuItem` programmatically, like this:

```
var pluginMenuItem = new MenuItem
{
    Header = "NewMenuItem, 
    Command = MenuItemCommand,
    CommandParameter = "{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"
};
```

This passes the `string` `"{Binding RelativeSource= {RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type MenuItem}}}"` as the `CommandParameter`.

What am I missing?

Comment: The syntax is a `XAML markup extension` and cannot be used in C# code. To find a parent element, you can use the `VisualTreeHelper` class in code

Comment: Using `VisualTreeHelper` in the ViewModel is violation of the MVVM pattern, as is using `MenuItem`. Both are defined in PresentationCore.dll and Presentation.dll respectively

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve thing using below mentioned code

your xaml code look like

```
 <Menu Name="menu" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuList,Mode=TwoWay}">
  </Menu>
```

Your ViewModel look like

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainViewModel class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        MenuList.Add(new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "MenuItem1",
            Command = MenuItemCommand,
            CommandParameter = "FirstMenu"
        });
        MenuList.Add(new MenuItem()
        {
            Header = "MenuItem2",
            Command = MenuItemCommand,
            CommandParameter = "SecondMenu"
        });
    }

    private ObservableCollection<MenuItem> _menuList;

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> MenuList
    {
        get { return _menuList ?? (_menuList = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>()); }
        set { _menuList = value; RaisePropertyChanged("MenuList"); }
    }

    private RelayCommand<string> _MenuItemCommand;

    public RelayCommand<string> MenuItemCommand
    {
        get { return _MenuItemCommand ?? (_MenuItemCommand = new RelayCommand<string>(cmd)); }
        set { _MenuItemCommand = value; }
    }

    private void cmd(string value)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a view type in the ViewModel is a violation of the MVVM pattern